# Can't find Serviceprincipal in the List of Azure AD Roleassignements

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to get a List of all Members of an Azure AD Role with the Graph API. Users and Groups with that Role are displayed properly. But there should be a Service Principal with that Role as well, but i can't find it with the Graph API. Does anyone know why & maybe how to get the Serviceprincipal as well?

I tested both Endpoint-options:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/{ID}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/%7BID%7D/members)
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId={ID}/members"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=%7BID%7D/members%22)

The Setup in Azure Portal:

[The role in Azure AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roqgT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> To get the service principal with that role you can make use of below **Graph Api** query:

```
GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/your service_principal_id/appRoleAssignedTo
```

Make sure to have below permissions before running the query :

[image]

**Note:** That only active assignments will be displayed in response when you ran the above query.

To know more in detail, you can refer this article [List appRoleAssignments granted for a service principal - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) .